# How to find the Lagrange in MATLAB using diff and symbolic variables

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, differential-equations

I am trying to use the Lagrange equation to output `ma = -kx` from the kinetic and potential energy of a mass on a spring, however I am encountering the errors below in both the following pieces of code. I understand that the error is stating that I cannot use a symbolic variable as the second argument of `diff` but in the MATLAB help documents, it states that for partial derivatives you write it in this format?

Method 1:

```
clear
clc

syms m K t x(t) x_dot(t)

T = 0.5 * m * x_dot^2
V = 0.5 * K * x^2

L = T - V

temp = diff(L, x_dot)
```

Method 2:

```
clear
clc

syms m K t x(t) x_dot

x_dot = diff(x)

T = 0.5 * m * x_dot^2
V = 0.5 * K * x^2

L = T - V

temp = diff(L, x_dot)
```

Error:

```
Error using sym/diff (line 26)
Arguments, except for the first, must not be symbolic functions.
```

If I remove the `(t)` from the symbolic initialiser for `x`, then the error goes away, but as far as I am aware, I will need `x` to be in terms of `t` later down the line as I’ll be differentiating `x_dot` with respect to `t` to get acceleration.

EDIT...

This is what I wanted to acheive, however I don't know if this can be done without introducing substitutions?

```
clear
clc

syms m K t x(t) v p

x_dot = diff(x);

T = 0.5 * m * x_dot^2;
V = 0.5 * K * x^2;

L_sym = T - V;

L1 = subs(L_sym, x_dot(t),v);
L = subs(L1, x(t), p);

temp = diff(L(t), v);

LHS = diff(subs(temp, v, x_dot(t)) / diff(t));
RHS = subs(diff(L(t), p), p, x(t));

eqn = LHS == RHS
```

Comment: You need `x(t)` so you can differentiate wrt `t`. But you also want to differentiate wrt `x_dot`. Why can’t you differentiate wrt `t` the same way you try to differentiate wrt `x_dot`?

Comment: I'm unclear where your looking when you say "differentiate wrt x_dot" in the first two pieces of code, that is the line that causes issue, in the edit, the only part I can see differentiating wrt x_dot is LHS?

Comment: When you do `temp = diff(L, x_dot)` in your first block of code, you differentiate `L` wrt `x_dot`. `L` depends on `x`. So you are computing the derivative of `x` wrt `x_dot`.

Comment: Ah i see what you mean. I saw matlab displaying ````L(t)```` and didn't think. However this is still eluding me as i can't seem to tell matlab that i want it to differentiate wrt the differential of x(t) without an error